# Could someone, please, explain me the implementation of the following "Kotlin Literal high order function"?

Tags: kotlin

I am a newbie in Kotlin, I just started to learn it,
I get the following code example about literal/high order function:

```
fun myHigherOrderFun(functionArg: (Int)->String) = functionArg(5)
println ( myHigherOrderFun { "The Number is $it" })
prints "The Number is 5"
```

Which I have difficulty to understand: the function myHigherOrderFun get a lambda function as parameter but i can't understand, where is the (Int) input parameter? I see is passed in functionArg(5)... but i can't realize how is possible that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `functionArg` must be a function which takes an `Int` and returns a `String`. `functionArg` is being called as `functionArg(5)`, i.e. it is being passed an `Int` and is expected to return a `String`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start from the beginning, in Kotlin functions are first-class types, just like numbers and Strings and stuff.  So a function can take another function as a parameter, and/or return a function as its result.  A function which does this is called a ‘higher-order function’.

And that's what you have in your example!  The line:

```
fun myHigherOrderFun(functionArg: (Int)->String) = functionArg(5)
```

defines `myHigherOrderFun()` as a function which takes one parameter, which is itself a function taking a single `Int` parameter and returning a `String`.  (`myHigherOrderFun()` doesn't specify an explicit return type, so it's inferred to be a `String` too.)

The next line is probably where things are less clear:

```
println(myHigherOrderFun{ "The Number is $it" })
```

The first non-obvious thing is that it's calling `myHigherOrderFun()` with a parameter.  Because that parameter is a lambda, Kotlin lets you omit the usual `(`…`)`, and use only the braces.

The other non-obvious thing is the lambda itself: `{ "The Number is $it" }`.  This is a literal function taking one parameter (of unspecified type).

Normally, you'd have to specify any parameters explicitly, e.g.: `{ a: Char, b: Int -> /* … */ }`.  But if there's exactly one parameter, and you aren't specifying its type, then you can skip that and just refer to the parameter as `it`.  That's what's happening here.

(If the lambda didn't reference `it`, then it would be a function taking no parameters at all.)

And because the lambda is being passed to something expecting a function taking an `Int` parameter, Kotlin knows that `it` must be an `Int`, which is why we can get away without specifying that.

So, Kotlin passes that lambda to the `myHigherOrderFun()`, which executes the lambda, passing `5` as `it`.  That interpolates it into a string, which it returns as the argument to `println()`.

Many lambdas take a single parameter, so `it` gets used quite a lot in Kotlin; it's more concise (and usually more readable) than the alternative.  See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) for more info.

Comment: your answer make me clear everything! Basically the "real" lambda should: {(n:Int)->"The Number is $n"}, shorted with "it" keyword as parameter and the input parameter is passed inside the myHigherOrderFun().

Comment: _Almost_ exactly right; I think that you need to remove the parens, as those are for destructuring (extracting the values from a Pair or List or other composite object).  (It's a little confusing that the type needs them, but the lambda itself doesn't...)

Comment: Oh.. that's right! My mistake reporting the lambda! Once again thanks for your detailed and punctual explaination!!!